# How to get PDF Name using UIWebView?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

In my iOS application (made in Objective-C) I print a pdf document in a `UIWebView`.
This `PDF` is display by my php page using `"Content-type: application/pdf"`

I want to get my `PDF` name for saving it in my device after this.

How could I do this please ?

Just below the code I use to connect to the `webservice` and print my pdf document in my `UIWebview`

```
self.factureWebView.delegate = self;

    NSURL *lienFacture = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://aaaa.com/app/facture.php"];


requete = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:lienFacture cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10];

[requete setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"idC=%@&mdpC=%@&idF=%@",idConnexion, mdpConnexion, idFacture];
NSData *data = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[requete setHTTPBody:data];

[self.factureWebView loadRequest:requete];
```

And this is my php file

```
$idConnexion = $_POST['idConnexion'];
$mdpConnexion = $_POST['mdpConnexion'];
$idFacture = $_POST['idFacture'];

ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0');

$wsdlURL = 'https://xxxx.com/Balm/Services_2_0.wsdl'; 
$ns = 'https://erp.xxxx.com/developerKey/';

$devKey = 'a1b2c3';

$soap = new SoapClient($wsdlURL);
$soap->__setSoapHeaders(new SoapHeader($ns, 'developerKey', $devKey));

$params = new stdClass();
$params->context = 'Client'; 
$params->login = $idConnexion; 
$params->password = $mdpConnexion;

$res = $soap->GetContactDevKey($params);

$devKey2 = $res->result;

$soap2 = new SoapClient($wsdlURL);
$soap2->__setSoapHeaders(new SoapHeader($ns, 'developerKey', $devKey2));

$res2 = $soap2->Authenticate($params);

$token = $res2->result->VisitorToken;

$demandsParam = new stdClass();
$demandsParam->visitorKey = $token;
$demandsParam->printType = 'PrintBill';
$demandsParam->id = $idFacture;
$factures = $soap2->GetClientPrint($demandsParam);

echo $factures->result->Content;
```

Comment: can u place PDF sample URL link how it looks like while loading PDF in webview...!

Comment: @Batman Do you want to open PDF in UIWebView right?

Comment: @Yuyutsu No my PDF is print by my UIWebView, it's work fine. But it want to get the name of the PDF file. I need it to save it locally on the iPhone / iPad.

Comment: @Vidhyanand900 my URL look like this I post beside, there is no URL link finishing with extension .pdf, my extension is .php

Comment: Upon clicking on any PDF on web view. U can find name of it..!

Comment: @Batman You mean to say you want all `pdf`file name which you save locally right?

Comment: @Vidhyanand900, no it's not show

Comment: @Yuyutsu, I say I want to get the name of PDF show in my UIWebView. With this name then, I would be able to save it locally on my device using "NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPDF" ofType:@"pdf"];"

Answer (score 0):

You can use below delegate method of webview to find name of PDF. Remember to set delegate of webView. Below method will be called everytime U click on any thing on webpage. So check while clicking on PDF on webview what PDFURL returns and get PDF name from it..!

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSLog(@"@@@@@@@@@@@@@Navigation Type is:%ld",navigationType);
    NSLog(@"url: %@ Scheme:%@ Host:%@", [[request URL] absoluteString], request.URL.scheme ,request.URL.host);

    NSString *pdfURL =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",request.URL];
    NSLog(@"@@@@@@@@@@@@@PDF URL String:%@",pdfURL);

    return YES;
}
```

You can get PDF URL from above...U can trim PDF name from it and store locally..

Hope it helps you..!

Comment: thanks, but it dont help me a lot

NSLog show me this

`@@@@@@@@@@@@@Navigation Type is:5`
`url: http://aaaa.com/app/facture.php Scheme:http Host: aaaa.com
@@@@@@@@@@@@@PDF URL String:http://aaaa.com/app/facture.php`

Answer (score 0):

Get your locally saved `PDF` filename list..

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];    
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *fileList = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory
                                                 error:nil];
// List file by name sort
NSLog(@"\n File list => %@",fileList);

//---- Sorting files by extension
NSArray *filePathsArray =
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory
                                                    error:nil];
//NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF EndsWith '.pdf'"]; //Change your extension here file sorted by your extension
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pathExtension='pdf'"];
    filePathsArray =  [filePathsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"\n\n Sorted files by extension %@",filePathsArray);
```

Comment: Nothing show in the 2nd NSLog

`File list => (
    "PDF_Documents"
)
 Sorted files by extension (
)`

Comment: Yes, I edit my first post and put my PHP code inside

Comment: first confirm you want to save file inside `NSDocumentDirectory` or somewhere else?

Comment: Here one tutorial : [tutorial](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/drawing-over-a-pdf-in-ios-pdf-template/)

Comment: Yes I want to save thanks to UIDocumentInteractionController. I find how to save, but I don't have the PDF name.